# jsRender template embeddable in jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, templates, jsrender

Can you place a jsRender template within a .js file? The reason is, I want to contain my entire plugin, which I want to have use a template instead of writing all the code to dynamically create the nodes, in a single javascript file. Is this possible? If so how? If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a template in a script block, you can get the compiled function, convert to string, and put it into your script file:

Run the code: `var compiledFunctionString = $( "#myTemplate" ).template().toString();`

Copy the string value of the resulting *compiledFunctionString* (which will be of the form `"function anonymous($data, $view) { ...content... }"`) and put it into your script file as: `function myTemplate($data, $view) { ...content... }`.

Now you can use it as in:

```
var html = $.render( data, myTemplate );
```

Comment: but I can't put a script block in a javascript file

Comment: No of course. My suggestion is not to put the script block in the javascript file, but to first create a separate html file with the template in a script block, and in the console or watch window evaluate the compiled template function as a string: $( "#myTemplate" ).template().toString(). Then you can copy that string (the function) into your plugin javascript file.

Comment: An alternative, though not as optimal for performance (since not pre-compiled) is just to provide the template as a string, in your script, as in the sample [02_compiling-templates-from-strings](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/step-by-step/02_compiling-templates-from-strings.html).

Comment: the whole problem is the ENTIRE plugin, templates and everything, need to be contained in a SINGLE javascript file. No external html, and completely independent of any web page. I guess the only pay is to write the template as a bunch of strings.

Comment: Neither approach above requires having more than one file. The HTML file in approach 1 is a tooling step for building your plugin js file. It doesn't need to be shipped as part of the plugin...

Comment: oh wait. I understand. kind of like compiling C++ code first, THEN distributing?

Comment: Hmm I got an error that said function template is not defined when I did: 
  
`$( "#myTemplate" ).template()`  
  
But this worked as per the [demo link](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/variants/accessing-templates/02_registering-named-template-from-script-declaration.html):  
  
`$.templates("#myTemplate")`  
  
@BorisMoore: Thank you, fantastic plugin!  
  
LordZardeck: (You would've probably found out by now) Not exactly like C++, because what's 'pre-compiled' here is only a generated Javascript function, which you'll be including inline in your JS file.

Comment: Is this still the way to do it? Am having some issues, even trying msanjay's fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103131/pre-compiling-jsrender-templates

Answer (score -1):

think about jQuery plugin: tmpl http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/

Comment: jQuery.tmpl is discontinued in favour of jsRender. See README: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl (and links from the README document).

Comment: In order to crate HTML code, we can create the nodes with `document.createElement` or using string in JavaScript. If the HTML structure is large and complex, we can write the structure with HTML markup in HTML file or JavaScript file, and then use template engine to render it, such as tmpl and [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)

Comment: What im asking is how exactly to place large, complex html code in a javascript file without using the dom manipulation.

Comment: Innerhtml is pointless. You can create a template sraight from a string